# Bluemix Nginx Proxy Not Working

Tags: nginx, transactions, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, bad-gateway

I have a Java backend app running on Bluemix, and it is working fine.  If I go to the backend server address:

```
http://backend.mybluemix.net/api/test
```

I get the expected response.  Now, I have a front-end application, deploying via the static buildpack, that works for serving the static assets, but I can't seem to get it to proxy to the back-end server correctly.

Here is my full nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

error_log /home/vcap/app/nginx/logs/error.log;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local]
  "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
  access_log /home/vcap/app/nginx/logs/access.log cloudfoundry;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include mime.types;
  sendfile on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript
  application/javascript application/x-javascript application/
  json application/xml application/xml+rss;

  tcp_nopush on;
  keepalive_timeout 30;
  port_in_redirect off; # Ensure that redirects don't include the internal container
  PORT - 63575
  server_tokens off;

  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %> ;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root /home/vcap/app/public;
      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;
    }
    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass      http://backend.mybluemix.net:80;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of URIs for the location and proxy_pass.  Here is the logging for the nginx install:

```
2016-01-12T10:05:13.785-0600[App/0]ERR[qtp1231318312-15]
    INFO spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
    The requested route [/api/test/] has not been mapped in Spark
2016-01-12T10:07:21.551-0600[App/0]ERR[qtp1231318312-19]
    INFO spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
    The requested route [/api/test/] has not been mapped in Spark
2016-01-12T10:07:24.679-0600[App/0]ERR[qtp1231318312-17]
    INFO spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
    The requested route [/api/test/] has not been mapped in Spark
2016-01-12T10:13:14.335-0600[App/0]ERR[qtp1231318312-16]
    INFO spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
    The requested route [/api/test/] has not been mapped in Spark

2016-01-12T10:13:14.325-0600[RTR/3]OUTbackend-1.mybluemix.net -
    [12/01/2016:16:13:14 +0000] "GET /api/test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 48
    "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
    KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
    108.168.250.156:36668 x_forwarded_for:"108.214.198.71"
    x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:71f1eefe-72fd-43e3-5aaf-45d5b72eede0
    response_time:0.005718652 app_id:9cbede6c-69a9-4830-932d-b830f12ddb38 
    x_global_transaction_id:"4197164295"
2016-01-12T10:18:23.952-0600[RTR/1]OUTbackend-1.mybluemix.net -
    [12/01/2016:16:18:23 +0000] "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1" 200 0 7
    "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
    108.168.250.153:48575 x_forwarded_for:"108.214.198.71"
    x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:c8d86b36-b3b9-4391-5e6d-9378ea3f36be
    response_time:0.006252107 app_id:9cbede6c-69a9-4830-932d-b830f12ddb38 
    x_global_transaction_id:"508431471"
```

That last one looks real promising - got a 200, but I still get an error when I go to:

```
http://frontend.mybluemix.net/api/test/
```

And the error is this:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

---

*Edit 1*
I have noticed that in some configurations, the request makes it through to the backend server, but the URI has a trailing slash appended, which throws off the server.

```
http://frontend.mybluemix.net/api/test
```

Becomes

```
http://frontend.mybluemix.net/api/test/
```